# Find the maximum value of a VB.Net DataTable

Tags: vb.net, datatable, integer, max

I have been very stumped by this one. I have a fairly large (~1500 x ~1000) DataTable of positive and negative integers *only* that I acquired from a .csv file. For my program, I need to find the maximum value *of the entire table*, not just in a single row or column. Optimally, the code would be short and sweet, but that's not always the case ;).

The name of my DataTable is `BeamMap` and I am trying to return a value of `MaxValue` (already declared as an integer). I can post the code I have for creating the DataTable upon request.

Extra Credit: (not really)

Is there a way to *quickly* find the location (ie., row,column) of said maximum value? So far, all of the examples I've seen check cell by cell for a predetermined value, which is rather inefficient for the number of data points that I have.

Comment: Are you reading in the csv file when you run the program? If so, could you check for min and max at that stage?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, when I run the program, I load the data from the csv file (selected by an open file dialog by the user) and immediately store it to the DataTable. If I can check at that stage, I don't know how.

Comment: A similar question was already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995526/return-max-value-with-linq-query-in-vb-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will do it. I haven't tried with a huge datatable so you will have to see how long it takes:

```
Private Function FindMaxDataTableValue(ByRef dt As DataTable) As Integer
    Dim currentValue As Integer, maxValue As Integer
    Dim dv As DataView = dt.DefaultView
    For c As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
        dv.Sort = dt.Columns(c).ColumnName + " DESC"
        currentValue = CInt(dv(0).Item(c))
        If currentValue > maxValue Then maxValue = currentValue
    Next
    Return maxValue
End Function
```

It sorts each column in turn and if the first value is larger than the current largest value it updates it.

For the extra credit you can do this but there might be a performance hit doing the `IndexOf` to find the `rowIndex`:

```
Private Function FindMaxDataTableValue(ByRef dt As DataTable) As Integer
    Dim currentValue As Integer, maxValue As Integer
    Dim rowIndex As Integer, colIndex As Integer
    Dim dv As DataView = dt.DefaultView
    For c As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
        dv.Sort = dt.Columns(c).ColumnName + " DESC"
        currentValue = CInt(dv(0).Item(c))
        If currentValue > maxValue Then
            rowIndex = dt.Rows.IndexOf(dv(0).Row)
            colIndex = c
            maxValue = currentValue
        End If
    Next
    Debug.WriteLine("Max value found at Col:" + colIndex.ToString + " Row:" + rowIndex.ToString)
    Return maxValue
End Function
```

Answer (score 14):

You can also use Compute("MAX(columnName),"") method to find maximum value on a column

```
Private Function FindMaxDataTableValue(ByRef dt As DataTable) As Integer

    Dim currentValue As Integer, maxValue As Integer
    maxValue = 0

    For c As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
        currentValue = dt.Compute("MAX(c)", "")
        If currentValue > maxValue Then maxValue = currentValue
    Next
    Return maxValue

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get user3549709's code to work as kept getting "Syntax error in aggregate argument: Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier." error. All my tables are filled manually and don't get their data from a database - I don't know if this makes a difference.

This is what I used instead to find the minimum and maximum values:

```
    Dim intcurrentValue As Integer
    Dim intmaxValue As Integer
    Dim intMinValue As Integer

    intmaxValue = 0
    intMinValue = 0

    For Each colMyColumn As DataColumn In dtDelta_E.Columns
        intcurrentValue = dtDelta_E.Compute("MAX([" & colMyColumn.ColumnName & "])", "")
        If intcurrentValue > intmaxValue Then intmaxValue = intcurrentValue
        intcurrentValue = dtDelta_E.Compute("MIN([" & colMyColumn.ColumnName & "])", "")
        If intcurrentValue < intMinValue Then intMinValue = intcurrentValue
    Next
```

Note: You only need the square brackets [] if you have spaces or the like in your column names